# objects titles are not passing to dropdown in multiple pages

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-templates, django-views

i created nav bar for ea ch pages and i want include a dropdown by passing model object title to the list
and its passing to main page but not passing to other pages

my template

```
 <li class="menu-has-children"><a href="#services">All Services</a>
     <ul style="display: inline;">
{% for detailinfo in detail.all %}
  <li><a href="{% url 'details' services.slug %}">{{ detailinfo.title }}</a></li>
{% endfor %}
</ul>
</li>
```

my view

```
def details(request, services_slug):
q = services.objects.filter(slug=services_slug)
if q.exists():
    q=q.first()
else:
    return HttpResponse("<h1> page not found </h1>")

detail = {'detail': q}

return render(request, 'detail.html', detail,)
```

and my this is my main page view it passed the titles in it but not in the detail

my main page view

```
def homepage(request):

aboutinfo = aboutpage.objects
servicesinfo = services.objects
programinfo = prgm.objects

return render(request, 'index.html', {'aboutinfo': aboutinfo, 'servicesinfo': servicesinfo, 
'programinfo': programinfo})
```

Comment: You should follow the docs [Retrieving all objects](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/db/queries/#retrieving-all-objects)

Answer (score 1):

you have to add .all() after the object to retrieve all objects

```
 servicesinfo= services.objects.all()
```

Comment: its in detail function that i cannot connect the objects